# Wireless Stops Working, Other Devices Kicked Off Network [Solved]

Tags: wireless

I just switched a PC to Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm getting some odd wireless network behaviour.

When I try to connect to my wireless, I have a brief connection followed by a disconnect. The thing is that every other device on my network also gets booted off (XBox360, Windows 10 laptop, 2 android phones). I can still see the network as available, but it won't establish a steady connection and my other devices won't connect at all.

I've tried to ping my IP address and I get one connection, followed by an endless series of messages saying the network could not be found, or that it could not connect.

Here are the results of my "lshw -c network"

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:25:64:8c:40:59
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:30 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:f7fff000-f7ffffff memory:cfff0000-cfffffff memory:f7fc0000-f7fdffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:5
       logical name: wlxc4e9840aae4f
       serial: c4:e9:84:0a:ae:4f
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

And here's the info on my "lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 -net"

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:02b7]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

This may also be of interest:

1. I'm connecting via a TP-Link (Model: TL-WN822N) Adapter;
2. When I disconnect my wi-fi on my PC, my other devices re-connect to    the network almost instantly (confirming for me that the problem is with Ubuntu);
3. I can't connect via Ethernet because the only phone jack in my apartment is in another room and I don't have a cord long enough to reach the PC. My Ethernet cable is currently connected to my XBox, and there is no change in behaviour if my XBox is turned off);
4. I tried using [this wireless script](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12350385#post12350385), but nothing happens when I run    it (regardless of whether the wireless is connected or not).

I apologize if this question has already been asked and answered, but I didn't see a similar situation where other household devices get booted off.

Comment: Before anything else, make sure you have the recommended wireless encryption settings: WPA2AES only! Not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. After that you may also need another driver. The wriless script you mentioned is useful for diagnostics but it does nothing besides creating a file with the report at  /home/your_username. Run it with the WiFi connected, find the resulting file, upload the contents to paste.ubuntu.com and edit your question with the given link.

Comment: My wireless doesn't have a WPA2-AES option in the security drop down. Only WPA/WPA2 Personal and Enterprise, and a bunch of WEP and LEAP options. I'm looking into how to make this available and am speaking with my provider. Thanks for the response...will update when I hear more.

Comment: The settings I mentioned are at the router managing that wireless network. You cannot change from the clients.

Comment: This solved the issue of regular disconnects and kicking other devices off the network. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. I'll turn it to an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the recommended wireless encryption settings:

WPA2-AES only! Not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.